# JSON Elements to Row OR JSON to table Row in MYSQL(Export JSON in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, normalization, mysql-json

We could have many request to store json to database. sometime we need to convert JSON Key set to Table - Rows.
How to extract complete json in Mysql table?

i.e. Having below json and requirement is to store each set as a row in the table.

```
'{
"log": [
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:19:55",
"Activity": "Activity 1"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:20:05",
"Activity": "Activity 2"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:20:31",
"Activity": "Activity 3"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:20:31",
"Activity": "Activity 4"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:21:03",
"Activity": "Activity 5"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:56:42",
"Activity": "Activity 6"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:56:53",
"Activity": "Activity 7"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:03",
"Activity": "Activity 8"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:04",
"Activity": "Activity 9"
}, 
{ "datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:53",
"Activity": "Activity 10"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:59",
"Activity": "Activity 11"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:58:01",
"Activity": "Activity 12"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:58:01",
"Activity": "Activity 13"
}
]
} '
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 has a JSON_TABLE function:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable 
  SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE('...your JSON ...', '$.log[*]' columns(
    rowid for ordinality, 
    dt datetime path '$.datetime', 
    activity varchar(20) path '$.Activity')
  ) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON can be stored in database with different datatypes.
i.e. JSON, VACRHAR, TEXT...etc.
For exporting a report or filtering the JSON element values, we should have different solutions to get it done.

**Creating a TABLE to store JSON in MySQL table.**

```
CREATE TABLE test_Json(id INT, activity_log JSON);
```

**Inserting a sample data into the table. JSON field data is inserted in JSON datatype, but it can be in VARCHAR or Text type as well.**

```
INSERT INTO test_Json(id, activity_log)
VALUES(1,
'{
"log": [
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:19:55",
"Activity": "Activity 1"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:20:05",
"Activity": "Activity 2"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:20:31",
"Activity": "Activity 3"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:20:31",
"Activity": "Activity 4"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 07:21:03",
"Activity": "Activity 5"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:56:42",
"Activity": "Activity 6"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:56:53",
"Activity": "Activity 7"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:03",
"Activity": "Activity 8"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:04",
"Activity": "Activity 9"
}, { "datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:53",
"Activity": "Activity 10"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:57:59",
"Activity": "Activity 11"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:58:01",
"Activity": "Activity 12"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-25 13:58:01",
"Activity": "Activity 13"
}
]
} ');

INSERT INTO test_Json(id, activity_log)
VALUES(2,'
{
"log": [
{ "datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:27",
"Activity": "Activity-11"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:27",
"Activity": "Activity-12"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:27",
"Activity": "Activity-13"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:27",
"Activity": "Activity-14"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:35",
"Activity": "Activity-15"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:49",
"Activity": "Activity-16"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:49",
"Activity": "Activity-17"
},
{
"datetime": "2017-10-29 21:56:49",
"Activity": "Activity-18"
}
]
}');
```

**Query to get JSON Exported as JSON Array with JSON Length value**

```
SELECT TJ.id,
JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(TJ.activity_log, '$**.datetime')) as Json_Length,
JSON_EXTRACT(TJ.activity_log, '$**.datetime') as json_array_message,
JSON_EXTRACT(TJ.activity_log, '$**.Activity') as json_array_datetime
FROM test_Json TJ
WHERE JSON_VALID(TJ.activity_log) = 1;
```

`JSON_VALID()` will validate JSON column data, whether JSON data is proper or not. If not, than it will be filtered out from query.

**Recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) to get n-Level element values in row format**

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE_json (id, array_datetime, array_message,seq) AS
(
SELECT id, 
JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(activity_log, '$**.datetime'), CONCAT('$[', 0, ']')), 
JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(activity_log, '$**.Activity'), CONCAT('$[', 0, ']')), 
0 as seq
FROM test_Json
UNION ALL
SELECT TJ.id, 
JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(TJ.activity_log, '$**.datetime'), CONCAT('$[', rc.seq +1, ']')) as array_datetime, 
JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(TJ.activity_log, '$**.Activity'), CONCAT('$[', rc.seq +1, ']')) as array_message, 
rc.seq +1 AS seq
FROM CTE_json rc
INNER JOIN test_Json TJ ON rc.id = TJ.id
WHERE rc.seq+1 < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(TJ.activity_log, '$**.datetime'))
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_json cj
ORDER BY id, seq;
```

If current MySQL version doesn't support recursive CTE, than we can use other LOOP alternatives.